# Laravel 5 php artisan not running in Vagrant, missing vendor/services.json?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Randomly I cannot run `php artisan` on a project via Vagrant SSH. It works outside of Vegrant SSH (regular terminal session). I am receiving the following error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                      
  file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/cvahimt/vendor/services.json): failed to open stream: Protocol error
```

I have tried everything I can think of - `php artisan clear-compiled`, `composer dump-autoload`, and removing `vendor` and running `composer install` again.

I noticed that `services.json` exists in my production environment but is absent locally. I cannot create it because `vendor` is read-only.

Also, when running `composer update` (with or without sudo) I receive this error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                                                  
  file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/cvahimt/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted
```

Kind of a problem, I need to run `php artisan migrate` and that only works via Vagrant.

Comment: Argh! To the user that posted the answer suggesting `chmod -R 777 vendor` please post it again - sorry, I tried this OUTSIDE of Vagrant and it fixed the problem. Want to give you credit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. change permissions on vendor folder `chmod -R 777 vendor`
2. run a `php artisan serve` and stop, this will create the services.json file.

Comment: Thanks! :) Any idea what causes this to happen? Was working fine at the end of work yesterday

Comment: Glad to help! Don't know why it happens, have the same issue here, but have no time to debug :) I hope it will be fixed in new L5 versions.

Comment: It works very well, but needs to be outside of the vagrant.... as here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cannot-run-artisan-in-vagrant-vendorservicesjson-missing